# Passing both data and HTML from php to javascript with Json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm new to all this so I apologize for any glaring errors.

I'm trying to use an ajax call from Javascript to select a random movie from a database, create some html with information about the movie and then also send an array of info back into a variable. I am using multiple php echo statements to do this. Of course the problem is that echo statements get pasted onto each other and so JSON can't parse it.

Ajax call:

```
var getOutput = function() {
    var movies = [];
    $.ajax({
        url:'on_movie_click.php',
        success: function (response) {
            $('#selection_area').html(response.responseText);
            console.log(response); #troubleshooting
            movies = JSON.parse(response);
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#selection_area').html('There was an error!');
        }
    });
    return movies;
}
```

php code:

```
//Getting info from database above
$index = [$movie_a,$movie_b];
echo json_encode($index);
echo "<div id='movie_a'><div id='movie_a_title'>$movie_a[1] </div><div id='movie_a_year'>($movie_a[2])</div></div>";
echo "<div id='movie_b'><div id='movie_b_title'>$movie_b[1] </div><div id='movie_b_year'>($movie_b[2])</div></div>";
```

The console.log in the ajax call outputs the stored array $index properly, but it also has the two `<div...` statements tacked on. JSON.parse throws an error because of this.

Is there any way to both store a variable ($index) back to a javascript variable (var movies), while also having the other two echo statements update the webpage using the same ajax call?

EDIT: Thanks kuma DK that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need the echoes with html markup to change your page. just use dom manipulation via javascript:

```
//first a function to create the movie div
//for the div id's you hand over the array index
function newMovieDiv(movie, index){
      //define the outer div
      var movieDiv = $("<div>").attr('id', 'movie' + index),
        //define the title div
        movieTitle = $("<div>").attr('id', 'movie' + index + 'title').text(movie[0]),
        //define the year div
        movieYear = $("<div>").attr('id', 'movie' + index + 'year').text("(" + movie[1] + ")");
      //put it all together and return it
      return movieDiv.append(movieTitle, movieYear);
 }
```

then you take your movies array and loop through it. call your function with the current item and its index and save the return value inside the variable movieItem. this then gets appended to whatever element you want to insert it into.

```
movies.forEach(function(item) {
  var movieItem = newMovieDiv(item, movies.indexOf(item)); 
  $("#movieList").append(movieItem);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/acL0dq4y/

of course, you'll have to adapt to your movies json. 
but this way, you only send the movies json from your server at the request and don't need to send the markup information with each php call

Answer (score 0):

When sending a json encoded information, you cant join it with text(HTML). If you want to send HTML or any other string, it also has to be wrapped with json. It will create a valid Json string and you still can get the HTML string by referring it from the Json result in client side.

Try something like this

```
//Getting info from database above
$index[] = array("data"=>$movie_a,"html"=>"<your html codes here>.........</end html>");
$index[] = array("data"=>$movie_b,"html"=>"<your html codes here>.........</end html>");
echo json_encode($index);
```